# Passing PowerShell $_ to external command

Tags: powershell, cmd

Is there to feed from PowerShell to an external command through a pipeline? For example can I do something like `Get-ADMember abc123 | net user /domain $_.samaccountname`? I know there are other ways to get it to work, I just want to focus on the communication between PowerShell and the external command.

Comment: Why not try it and see if it works?

Comment: Tried it already, if it worked I wouldn't be posting here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, something like that.  Pipelines in CMD and most shells are just text, and `$_.samaccountname` is a string.

Your example is very close.  All you're missing is a call to `Foreach-Object`, to do the iteration and populate the `$_` variable.

```
get-admember abc123 | foreach { net user /domain $_.samaccountname }
```

The pipelines aren't actually "linked" in any special way.  This command simply expands the variable and passes it as a command-line argument to the `net.exe` program.

Comment: OK, many thanks; I guess I am still puzzled by the fact that we are using foreach when get-admember will give only one result if the id exists.